# What is official procedure regarding a tag which will no longer be used?

Tags: support, tags

The tag [intel-xdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intel-xdk) will no longer be used (and hasn't been used for quite a while now) because Intel officially deprecated it a while back:

> [Intel® XDK has been discontinued. Below are alternative resources for building mobile HTML5 applications with Apache Cordova* software. Intel offers a portfolio of tools to help IoT developers go from rapid prototyping to production. Try Arduino Create* for a streamlined prototyping experience and Intel® System Studio for an all-in-one development tool suite.](https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk)

The last question was asked on *Sep 4 '18 at 5:10* which was asking how an older version could be used and the crux of the answer was that there would be no point as Intel had retired the back-end services which the software relied on.

In this instance, we can safely assume this tag won't be used so is there any official procedure in place for this?

Is there any way to "archive" the tag or is it just left as is?

<sup>I don't believe a burniation request would be appropriate because you can't just replace the [intel-xdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intel-xdk) tag with something else.</sup>

Comment: Is there a reason "doing something" is necessary?

Comment: @psubsee2003 nope, absolutely not, which is why I asked: '*Is there any way to "archive" the tag **or is it just left as is?***' - I'm just curious if there is a process in place for this sort of scenario, even if that process is "leave it".

Comment: The proper way is to add a note about deprecation in the tag wiki. Which someone has already done, so all is well.

Comment: @Lundin I added the note but was wondering if anything else was needed.

Comment: Then maybe you can answer what Arduino has to do with anything? Since it has absolutely nothing to do with web development or the topic...? Arduino is unsuitable for pretty much anything that isn't free time hobbyist tinkering. It is especially unsuitable for IoT.

Comment: @Lundin I simply copied and pasted Intel's original deprecation notice as was shown on their site.

Comment: Doesn't look like a copy/paste from this at all https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk. You should pute copy/paste inside quote formatting and state the source.

Comment: And wow, Intel suggesting Android for IoT... this is a whole new level of incompetence. They should go home and make PC computers instead...

Comment: @Lundin my mistake, it was snippets from this forum post: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-xdk/topic/722218

Comment: OK well, it isn't very meaningful. Right now it looks as if these are SO's recommendations. I'll edit the wiki.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When a company discontinues a product, the existing installations of that product do not automagically disappear from the planet.

There could be users that for one reason or another have ask a question about this technology. Or that they are looking for existing answers on this technology. Maybe because they have to migrate out of that technology, or understand code written for it.

If someone applies the tag incorrectly, someone else can always edit it and correct it. It already happens [very often](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/select) without needing the tag to be about an "obsolete" technology.

No need to do anything about this tag, or any "obsolete" tags.

As with any "retired" [technology](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-3.1)<sup>*****</sup>, tags and questions can be left there for future techno-archeologists to peruse, or for the ocassional new question to come around.

<sup>***** Latest question asked 18 hours ago? That was unexpected.</sup>

Comment: It also doesn't mean everyone will stop using it just like that.

Comment: @Zoe In this specific case, using the technology apparently requires backend services that are no longer functional. But even then, the answer is the same.

Comment: @Zoe in this instance, you have no choice, they retired the back-end services which was used throughout the build process and without them, the build would hang.

Comment: @Script47 I've seen some retiring services where the community created alternatives. If the only issue is the build backend, it wouldn't surprise me if someone who really liked the tech made an alternative.

Comment: @Zoe fair enough, never thought about it like that.